# When trying to start a thread in my base class, Visual Studio aborts my program due to a debug error

Tags: c++

When I start my thread from my base class, it runs fine, then Visual Studio tells me that there is an abort error.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 19, and when I debug my program Visual Studio shows me a break point "(x)" right after I create the new thread and 
an error message pops along with a dialog asking me if I would like to abort, retry, or ignore.

It looks something like this:

---

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

(x) Debug Error!

Program: C\Users\Super\Desktop\Void\Debug\Void.exe

abort() has been called

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---

If I don't create a new thread, and I just call the "run()" function, the program runs without any debug errors.

//This is the code that starts the thread

```
void Application::start()
{
    std::thread newThread(&Application::run, this);

    while (!running)
    {
        std::cout << "Not Running!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

//This is the code that the application runs

```
void Application::run()
{
    setup();
    running = true;

    //using namespace std::chrono;

    auto lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    double delta = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    while (running)
    {
        setTargetTPS(60);
        auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        delta += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now - lastTime).count() / ns;

        lastTime = now;

        while (delta > 1)
        {
            update();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        if     (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - timer).count() > 1000)
        {
            timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            tps = ticks;
            ticks = 0;

            std::cout << "TPS: " << tps << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

//Game is a subclass of Application, I use it like this

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game* game = new Game();
    game->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::thread newThread(&Application::run, this);` the thread goes out of scope when `void Application::start()` ends.

Comment: `while (running)` ... `running = true;` - the `running` variable is accessed/modified from multiple threads. It needs synchronization. And I'll bet that's not the only data-race in your code.

Comment: There is also missing a `detach` or `join` which would lead to a crash later on

Comment: Multithreaded programming is much more than figuring out how to start multiple threads.  You have to learn synchronization techniques also, and that in itself is not a trivial topic.

Comment: I'll bet you could remove at least 90% of that code and still get the problem. Once you've eliminated distractions, if you can see what's wrong in the code you're done. If you can't, post the **smallest** program you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is the point of threading to run asynchronous processes?

Comment: Yes, that is the point.  But there is much more to it than just starting threads.  Mutexes, semaphores, atomic variables, condition variables, etc.  Look at your `running` variable.  As the comment before pointed out, if that is a static variable, or if it isn't static but you're accessing the same object instance, that `run` function is not thread safe.

Comment: Also what do you thing would happen when you exit main if you have secondary threads running. Your code must manage its threads. Beside that, it make no sense to start a thread if main thread does nothing no even waiting!

Comment: Multithreaded code without proper synchronization between threads would be like blind people running through an intersection with heavy traffic. You will get crashes.

Comment: @Phil1970 -- it isn't self-evident that there's something wrong with exiting `main` while other threads are running. In Java, if I remember correctly, that's perfectly okay, and the program continues to run until all the threads have terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) already commented, when `Application::start` finishes (which is immediately after `Application::run` changes `running` to `true`, which happens at its *start*) the destructor of `newThread` is called.

According to [the cppreference page for Thread::~thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread), the destructor of a currently-running `thread` calls `std::terminate()`, which according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) calls (by default) `std::abort()`, leading to the message you see.

In short, you can't have a running `Thread` going out of scope.
If it fits, you can simply call `newThread.join()` in `Application::start`, which will hold it until the thread finishes.

Or you can call `newThread.detach()`. This will make `newThread` saparate from the main thread, making it impossible to `join` - which can be good or bad, it depends on your needs. In this state, albeit the thread itself still running, the `newThread` variable could be destructed in peace (as detaching a thread disconnects it from the variable in which it's held).

Comment: @SuperSim135 You'd need to create more `Thread` objects, but yeah, sure.